# HTML form to upload file and execute bash command

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, calibre

I have a Raspberry Pi (Debian/Wheezy) running Calibre (v 0.8.51) headless as a ebook server and Apache2. I want to ease the upload of ebooks to my calibre library creating a HTML form. The form submit button needs to tirgger a script doing the following:

- Pass to a bash command variables containing authors, title, ISBN, tags;
- Upload to a a specific location (/home) the file after renaming it to book.mobi;
- Run the following bash command
  `calibredb add --library-path=/home/calibre-library --authors "$authors" --title "$title" --tags "$tags" --isbn "$isbn" /home/book.mobi`
  What would be the best method to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You need server side scripting to handle the data from the form POST and further process it.
So the answer would depend on your language preference.

1. If you know/like PHP you can POST the form to a PHP page. The PHP script will then retrieve the POST parameters. Using **exec**, you can then call your custom scripts. This should be quick to do. You may refer to exec command documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).
2. If you know Python, you could pick up any web framework. Ihad mentioned a few in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207533/connecting-python-mysql-and-html/16207623#16207623)
3. Or you could use any other language

I am biased towards Python since it is inherently supported in RPi and also it is not too tough to do OS operations and bash script execution as you desire.